# Android No Launcher Icon

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app and somehow after fixing up some things in the manifest file there is no app icon so I cannot launch the app from the app drawer anymore :/ I was looking at some other threads but they gave me no luck

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <data android:scheme="db-XXX" />
        <meta-data
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXX-XXX" />


        <activity

            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard">
            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make sure your folder 4 mipmap folders exists in folder res, and...

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

app icon determine from here  `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

make sure this path is not Empty and make sure you have ic_launcher in all other drawable folers

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: I dont have exact that path, but like mipmap-xhdp etc

Comment: Ctrl on this , will direct you to the file

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your code:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

You have to check if this path is correct (If you have an Android Studio's project, you have to go to your project's folder, go to "app>src>main>res>mipmap" and check if there is a image file called "ic_launcher" -probably a PNG-).

Good look